# what's the difference between CCCallFunc and CCCAllFuncN

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Yeah, not sure I understand the difference.
Because you can specify the target object by using CCCallFunc as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CCCallFuncN passes the CCNode you called the action on to the method. For example if you need to run an action that removes the node from its parent you can use CCCallFuncN and then said method would look like this:

```
-(void)theCalledMethod:(CCNode *)thePassedNode
{
  [thePassedNode.parent removeChild:thePassedNode];
}
```

If you used a CCCallFunc instead you would have to keep a reference to said node in order to be able to retrieve it later and remove it in the called method.

Comment: The difference in behavior between these two methods is *extremely* important to remember. Recently, I had an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a callback that was driving me crazy; Instruments couldn't find any Zombies, and the very few retains I had all seemed correct. Turned out that I was invoking my callback with CCCallFunc() instead of CCCallFuncN(). Since CCCallFunc() does not pass the CCNode directly to your callback, the callback's attempts to operate on the sender were crashing my app. It's amazing how an 'N' can be the difference between a crashing app and a perfectly working on.